# How to extend javascript class in ECMA5(IE11) ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

IE11 does not support ECMA Script 6.
So I cannot use "class" syntax in IE11.
Then,how to extend obj in IE11(ECMA5) ?

```
//only ECMA6+ 
// do not work in IE11
    class ChildObj extends google.maps.LatLng {
        constructor(child) {
            super(Number(child.lat), Number(child.lng));
            this.additionalProp = child;
        }
    }
//ECMA5  -> ????
```

I do not know what is the correct way to define child class, e.g. ChildObj shown above ,in ECMA5.

I think that jquery $.extend is not extending , but merging properties.
So , how to call parent class constructor in child class?

Comment: read this https://scotch.io/tutorials/better-javascript-with-es6-pt-ii-a-deep-dive-into-classes

Comment: use http://babeljs.io/repl/ - paste your code in the left hand side - copy the code from the right hand side

Comment: yet another explanation of how es6 classes are comiled to es5 http://stackoverflow.com/a/35776188/2379922

Comment: @BekimBacaj Provide some reasoning instead of snarky comments

Answer (score 2):

[According to MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Classical_inheritance_with_Object.create()), you would do:

```
function childObj() {
    google.maps.LatLng.call(this);
}

childObj.prototype = Object.create(google.maps.LatLng.prototype);
childObj.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
```

But a simpler solution if you want to use ES6 components but still have ES5 code, is to use a transpiler. For example [babel](https://babeljs.io) would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly, you can use `$.extend()`

```
let opt = function opt(child) {
            // set plain object without properties at first parameter to create
            // new object, set plain object at last parameter
            // to change properties at `data`
            return $.extend({}, data.maps.LatLng, child, {additionalProp:child});
          }
let option = new opt({lat:0,lng:1});
```