# Defining internal class variables inside class methods using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

This questions is actually React JS related. Is it OK to define internal class variables inside one of the class methods and then use it in other methods? I mean to do something like this:

```
class Something extends React.Component {
  state = {
      value: 'doesnt matter'
  };

  something = () => {
    //a lot is happening in here and at some point I define this.thing
    this.thing = 1;
  }

  increase = () => {
    if(this.thing) {
      this.thing += 1;
    }
  }

  decrease = () => {
    if(this.thing && this.thing > 0) {
      this.thing -= 1;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>this.state.value</span>
    );
  }
}
```

thing is that I don't need to put that `this.thing` as a state value, because I only need it internally. Please be aware that this code is just an example, real code is a bit more complicated, but the main question, is it OK to define class internal variables(`this.thing`) like I do in my example? Or maybe I should do this differently? What would be the best practice?

Comment: The variable "thing" is a variable class and it can be accessed in all methods you define in this class.
It's the same if you fine it in your state:

state = {
  value: "...",
thing: null
}

Comment: You might check out https://medium.freecodecamp.org/where-do-i-belong-a-guide-to-saving-react-component-data-in-state-store-static-and-this-c49b335e2a00 Just using `this` like you're doing looks to be one nice option

Comment: @DaniloAssisNobredosSantos That's only a good idea if a change to `thing` should necessarily always trigger a re-render - otherwise, best to store `thing` elsewhere, I think

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instance property in React ES6 class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849220/instance-property-in-react-es6-class)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem to use the constructor to do such a thing but based on the react theory and UI rendering this kind of usage will not re-render or follow the react pattern of trigger and re-render, it will just server as a storage for a value that has nothing to do with the react life cycle.

```
class Something extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Your thing
    this.thing = 0;
    this.state = {
      value: "doesnt matter."
    };
  }

  something = () => {
    //a lot is happening in here and at some point I define this.thing
    this.thing = 1;
  };

  increase = () => {
    if (this.thing) {
      this.thing += 1;
    }
  };

  decrease = () => {
    if (this.thing && this.thing > 0) {
      this.thing -= 1;
    }
  };

  render() {
    this.something();
    console.log(this.thing); // will equal 1.
    return <span>{this.state.value}</span>;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, I know I can use constructor and define variables there, but question is, is it necessary to define all `this.something` vars in constructor? if so, why? 
Another thing regarding rerendering, I don't need component to rerender when that value is changing, so I am aware of that. Question still stays, is it normal practice or is it wrong to use such patterns with `this.thing` as I use in my example? :)

Comment: It's not a problem and nothing wrong, above all React is javascript and this.{Anything} is a valid class/Object prototype.

Comment: so, there is no rules/best practices for how and when this.{anything} can be defined?

Comment: In the constructor, check this for how it’s defined and how it’s translated behind the scene by babel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774928/how-does-babel-js-create-compile-a-class-declaration-into-es2015

Answer (score 0):

> I don't need to put that this.thing as a state value, because I only need it internally.

A React component's `state` should also only be used internally.

> What would be the best practice?

You can use instance variables (ivars) instead of state to **increase performance** because you may reduce the burden on the event queue. Aesthetically, ivars often require **less code**. But state updates are usually preferred because they will trigger a re-render; this guarantee makes your code **easier to think about**, as the render is never stale. In your case, the render function is independent of `this.thing`, so it's okay to store it in an ivar.

Generally, it's best to initialize ivars in the [constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) because it runs first, so `this.thing` is guaranteed to be ready for consumption by other methods:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.thing = 0;
}
```

Comment: I do undestand how constructor works and I know state workflow as well. What I am not sure about is, can I define ivars wherever I want, or there is some rules/best practices for that? Like is it really necessary to define them in constructor? anyway thanks for you answer :)

Comment: You can initialize ivars anywhere, but you might get unexpected behavior if the code that reads `this.thing` somehow gets run before `this.thing` is initialized. Even if you code it correctly, when I (an outside contributor) open your codebase, I'll be uncertain if you did it right. That uncertainty is eliminated if you initialize `this.thing` in the constructor.